# same scale on x y axis in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot a trajectory using Javascript and highcharts, similarly to this minimal example:

```
$(function () { 

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'PLOT'
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'X'
        },
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Y'
        },
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Trajectory',
        data: [[1,2],[5,0],[0,0],[3,4]]
    }]
  });
});
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3614/ )

Since the unit for the values on x and y is meters, I would like to scale equally both the axis, otherwise my trajectory will end up being highly distorted (if you're familiar with Matlab, I want to reach the same result as in the 'axis equal' option for the standard matlab 'plot' function:
[image]
)

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve the same result in highcharts?
Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control width and height for x/yAxis setting `width`/`height` options: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3622/

```
    xAxis: {
        height: 200, 
        width: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'X'
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 6
    },

    yAxis: {
        height: 200,            
        width: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Y'
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 6
    },
```

I also added `min` and `max` to make sure both axes have the same scale.

Comment: Thank you! The combination of min/max and heigth/width in axis properties solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tickInterval with min and max on X and Y Axis : http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3620/

```
xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 2,
    min: 0,
    max: 6,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint Raeen, however your solution seems to be still influenced by the size of the div container. Looking for a more responsive solution I've tried to build a (almost) square <div> container and then use min and max attributes in the plot just as you suggested. http://jsfiddle.net/b263s37w/2/

Comment: So set the `width` and `height` of the `container` yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/b263s37w/3/