# Highcharts plot with equal axes scaling

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts

I'm trying to plot a 2d trajectory using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). My current minimal example is shown below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#container').highcharts({
            series: [{
                data: [[1, 2], [2, 2.01], [3, 2]],
            }],
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**How can I enforce equal scaling for both axes?**
In my example the vertical axis is way too stretched.

I've seen [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27015136/3419103) setting `width`, `height`, `min` and `max` for both axes. But since I'm creating this plot programmatically and I don't know the size of the rendered `div`, it's hard to set these values.

Comment: In other words, you mean to have always square chart?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the chart is rendered with a width of twice its height (depending on the container), the x range should be twice as large as the y range - so that the x *resolution* in terms of pixels per unit is the same as the y *resolution*.

Comment: How about using [tickPixelInterval]() option on the both axis? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPixelInterval

Comment: @SebastianBochan: That only controls the tick frequency, not the axis scaling itself. [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpixelinterval-50/)

Comment: Only what comes to my mind is extract height from yAxis (in load event) and then calculate size of chart and trigger [setSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.setSize) function.